# Converting apache .htaccess to nginx (mod_rewrite)

Tags: nginx, converters

Could someone help me understand how to work Nginx in case I use mod_rewrite. I used Apache2 in the past, but I was recommended to use Nginx for better stability, but my site uses mod_rewrite to make the pages friendlier, but now I have the problem to convert this in Nginx. Following is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?game=$1
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try online converters? Like https://winginx.com/en/htaccess ?

Comment: It will be something similar to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?game=$uri;`

Answer (score 0):

Using [this converter](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx) produces the correct result:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?game=$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding, but where would I put this text?